# Routing issues when called from index page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have implemented dynamic drop down using jQuery, it worked for me in the “new” page, but fails in the “index” page

I have a parent drop down called “projects” and child dropdown called “tests”. Upon selecting a project, the tests drop down should be updated.

In “new” page (view), when I select the parent drop down, it is calling “/results/update_tests?xxxxx”. However when I selected the project in “index” page, “/update_tests?” is called and failed with the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] “/update_tests”):
```

Any idea, why "/updated_test?" is called when I am calling from "/results/index" page?

Here is My routes configuration:

```
get ‘results/update_tests’, as: ‘update_tests’
```

Comment: How are you creating the link? And if you inspect the HTML code after it's created, how does that look? The problem is because the link in your case is relative to the path you are at, and just adds the "update_tests" part at the end of the current URL.

Comment: I am using the following coffee script to generate the URL.                                                                                                                      $ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#projects_select_index', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_tests'

Comment: After changing the code   $ -> $(document).on 'change', '#projects_select_index', to generate the link, it is working fine.  But still I didn't understood how the same code worked in 'new' page.  There it was appending "/update_tests" to "results". But not happening in "index" page.